# Assigning a variable to a value chosen in a loop in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

What I'm doing here is working - I'm just wondering if there's a better or more efficient way to accomplish the same thing.

Here's the XML structure

```
<tags>
     <tag>
          <val1>abc</val1>
          <val2>123</val2>
     </tag>
        <tag>
          <val1>def</val1>
          <val2>456</val2>
     </tag>
     <tag>
          <val1>ghi</val1>
          <val2>789</val2>
     </tag>
</tags>
```

I need to assign a variable to the value of val2, but ONLY if val1 = 'def'
So in the end I want a variable that will be equal to the value of 456

It's guaranteed that these values will be unique, so 'def' will only exist once

The way I solved this is to assign the variable to the value in a loop checking for the value I'm looking for

```
<xsl:variable name="id">
     <xsl:for-each select="tags/tag">
          <xsl:variable name="role"><xsl:value-of select="val1"/ </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:if test="$role = 'def'">
               <xsl:value-of select="val2"/>
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>
```

This solution works and is correctly assigning the value 456 to the variable 'id', but it's a little slow, so I was wondering if there are any alternative solutions that I might not be thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply select the element with `<xsl:variable name="id" select="tags/tag[val1 = 'def']/val2"/>` or define a key `<xsl:key name="val2-by-val1" match="tags/tag/val2" use="../val1"/>` and then select `<xsl:variable name="id" select="key('val2-by-val1', 'def')"/>`.

Comment: I tried out the first method and it shaved off several minutes of processing time. Thanks for your help